# Speeding up a test with factories with an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an integration test that uses Paperclip and a factory with `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` to `(:create`) an image `20.times`.

This test is extraordinarily slow. It took over 60 seconds to complete. I swapped out the image with one 30x smaller, and it only cut the test time by 20 seconds.

How can I speed up this test and others like it?

Comment: please post the content of the test and the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to stub imagemagick since that's the part which slows down the tests the most.

You can try something like [this](https://gist.github.com/gabrielecirulli/6340651) or [this](https://gist.github.com/ngauthier/406460)

And, in case that you are not using paperclip (which I just assumed...) You can maybe use something like [mockfs](http://mockfs.github.io/), which stubs your filesystem in tests to speed it up.